# Don't accept any operation in Main, unless other form closses

Tags: c#, forms, parent-child

My question is that as in IDM and Winrar, when we click on any option like on "Add" in winrar and in IDM on "Add URL". The main window stays in the background but cannot accept user click and we have to close the operation in front first in order to make interaction again with main form.

I want the same with my windows forms and I am not using parent child relation.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is [`form2.ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `form2.Show()` to open the second form [modally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window), disabling the first form. The `ShowDialog` method is also blocking call, which means the next line will only be run once the new form is closed.

> You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your application. When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed. The dialog box can be assigned one of the values of the DialogResult enumeration by assigning it to the DialogResult property of a Button on the form or by setting the DialogResult property of the form in code. This value is then returned by this method.